# How to import a SDF or sd file in python?

Tags: python, chemistry, rdkit, cheminformatics

This would be my first time asking a problem here and I am a bit new to programming so please bear with me. Now, I was trying to import a list of compounds from ChemBL so as to get these compounds to be displayed in a grid and categorize them. Problem I am facing is that, everytime I try to import the SDF it gives a error sayin bad input file.
Now I tried mentioning the path of the SDF I downloaded and I also tried putting the actual name of the file but still the same error persists. I feel like I am doing some silly mistake but I can't really pin it down.
Now, would I have to enter the data of every compound as a **.sdf** file and then print it?

```
INPUT
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
sd_supplier = Chem.SDMolSupplier(r'C:\Users\abc\Downloads\DOWNLOAD-kFj-7sO59mDkb3HHrtKd0_C9Qh8SCpVsEFJstjEfSUw=\DOWNLOAD-kFj-7sO59mDkb3HHrtKd0_C9Qh8SCpVsEFJstjEfSUw=.sdf')*
for mol in sd_supplier:
    name = mol.GetProp('Name')
    smiles = Chem.MolToSmiles(mol)
    print(f'Molecule: {name}')
    print(f'SMILES: {smiles}')
```

```
OUTPUT
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-a625f28bcf9e> in <cell line: 2>()
---->3 sd_supplier = Chem.SDMolSupplier(r'C:\Users\abc\Downloads\DOWNLOAD-kFj-7sO59mDkb3HHrtKd0_C9Qh8SCpVsEFJstjEfSUw=\DOWNLOAD-kFj-7sO59mDkb3HHrtKd0_C9Qh8SCpVsEFJstjEfSUw=.sdf')
```

```
OSError: File error: Bad input file C:\Users\abc\Downloads\DOWNLOAD-kFj-7sO59mDkb3HHrtKd0_C9Qh8SCpVsEFJstjEfSUw=\DOWNLOAD-kFj-7sO59mDkb3HHrtKd0_C9Qh8SCpVsEFJstjEfSUw=.sdf
```

(* this line throws the error every time, I tried with putting in the actual name of the SDF but still it didn't work, I tried with the file path, and still it throws the error.)

Comment: what does C:\Users\abc\Downloads\DOWNLOAD-kFj-7sO59mDkb3HHrtKd0_C9Qh8SCpVsEFJstjEfSUw=\DOWNLOAD-kFj-7sO59mDkb3HHrtKd0_C9Qh8SCpVsEFJstjEfSUw gives you in your file explorer ?

Comment: Hi, is your sd file in text format ?  I'm asking because, for example, a download might be in a binary format, and the filename will look a bit like the one you have.